# htaccess redirect index.php?v=1 to index.html

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect this page /index.php?route=common/home to index.html

and have put this in my .htaccess page:

Redirect 301 index.php?route=common/home index.html

However, I get a 500 Internal Server Error when I do this.

Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

(Note: there are other pages example /index.php?route=checkout which I don't want to redirect)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`Redirect` is just really used to make aliases (and is part of `mod_alias`). Instead, you need to use `mod_rewrite`, so `RewriteRule /index.php?route=common/home index.html [R=301]` *should* work, but check it first.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. So I changed the code to this:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /index.php?route=common/home index.html [R=301]
But is still did not work.
Any other ideas?

Comment: You also need `RewriteEngine On` somewhere. If that doesn't work, I'm not too sure as I can't 100% remember mod_rewrite syntax, maybe remove the leading slash.